# Sencha Touch setActiveItem shows animation then requires click to show

Tags: xcode4, ios5, cordova, sencha-touch

When I move between views in my Sencha Touch app I see the animation (slide), then the original view(the one I started at) is shown again. At that point, if I click anywhere in the app the view will change to the correct newly active item.

I'm using Sencha Touch, XCode 4, iOS 5 SDK, and PhoneGap 1.3.0.

Thanks in advance!

here's the code for the main viewport:

```
plantanalyzer.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
fullscreen: true,
layout: 'card',
cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
initComponent: function() {
Ext.apply(plantanalyzer.views, {
          login: new plantanalyzer.views.Login(),
          plantDetail: new plantanalyzer.views.PlantDetail(),
          buildingList: new plantanalyzer.views.BuildingList()
          });
Ext.apply(this, {
          items: [
                  plantanalyzer.views.login,
                  plantanalyzer.views.plantDetail,
                  plantanalyzer.views.buildingList
                  ]
          });


   plantanalyzer.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

and for the viewController:

```
plantanalyzer.controllers.viewController = new Ext.Controller({
index: function(options) {
    plantanalyzer.views.viewport.setActiveItem(plantanalyzer.views.plantDetail, options.animation);
},
show: function(options) {
    plantanalyzer.views.viewport.setActiveItem(plantanalyzer.views.buildingList, 

options.animation);
    }
});
```

and this is the code for one of the views:

```
plantanalyzer.views.PlantDetail = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
width: 320,
height: 480,
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'panel',
        html: '<img src="images/logo.jpg"/>',
        tpl: '{name}',
        cls: 'plantToolbar'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        name : 'buildingSelect',
        text: 'Select Building',
        cls: 'standardButton',
        listeners: {
            'tap': function () {
                'use strict';
                Ext.dispatch({
                    controller: plantanalyzer.controllers.viewController,
                    action: 'show'
                });
            }
        }
    },
    {
        xType: 'panel',
        cls: 'infoBoxes',
        html: 'Efficiency (kw/ton)<br><canvas id="eff"></canvas>'
    },
    {
        xType: 'panel',
        cls: 'infoBoxes',
        name: 'totalTons',
        html: 'Total Plant Tons: '
    },
    {
        xType: 'panel',
        cls: 'infoBoxes',
        name: 'totalCost',
        html: 'Real-time Plant Cost: '
    },
    {
        xType: 'panel',
        name: 'uodateTime',
        cls: 'lastUpdate',
        html: 'Last Update: '
    }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine in both sections. When i had issues with phonegap and sencha touch doing this i generally found there was a javascript error occurring or extra html markup was in between the body tag of the index.html file. The first thing would be to open the console in chrome or safari and check the javascript console to determine if it is a javascript error. If you can't run it in them i would suggest the Wienre application that will give you a console and was written to debug phonegap applications (wienre will also allow you to view the html markup to make sure it is correct)

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking it out now. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: No luck, checked for errors with Weinre, ran all my JS files through JSLint, and ran my index.html through HTMLlint. No leads... any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be somewhere in the view files. The code you have shown is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, after rebuilding the app I found the issue. It was some custom css that was screwing up the app. Specifically the width that was being set on some of the components. 
Hopefully, this will save somebody else some time and heartache.

Thanks, Darren and Ilija for your help!